# How can I see how long my Cloud Run deployed revision took to spin up?

Tags: google-cloud-run

I deployed a Vue.js and a Kotlin server app. Cloud Run does promise to put a service to sleep if no request to it arise for a specific time. I did not opened my app for a day now. As I opened it - it was available almost immediatly. Since I know how long it takes to spin up when started locally I kinda don't trust the promise that Cloud Run really had put the app to sleep and span it up so crazy fast.

I'd love to know a way how I can really see how long it took for the spinup - also for startup improvement for the backend service.

Answer (score 0):

After having the service inactive for some time, record the time when you request the service URL and request it.

Then go to the logs for the Cloud Run service, and use this filter to see the logs for the service:

```
resource.type="cloud_run_revision"
resource.labels.service_name="$SERVICE_NAME"
```

Look for the log entry with the normal app output after your request, check its time and compare it with the recorded time.

Comment: Ok will try that. A follow up question: The _Billable instance time_ monitor of the cloud run service dashboard - is this the time the pod/container is running? O

Answer (score 0):

You can't know when the instance will be evicted or if it is kept in memory. It could happen quickly, or take hours or days before eviction. it's "serverless".

About the starting time, when I test, I deploy a new revision and I have a try on it. In the logging service, the first log entry of the new revision provides me the cold start duration. (Usually 300+ ms, compare to usual 20 - 50 ms with warm start).

The billing instance time is the sum of all the containers running times. A container is considered as "running" when it process request(s).